# Trying to assign random index value to a variable (learning to code!)

Tags: javascript, function

I've been learning to code for a few months now and i'm slowly starting to build my own very simple heads or tails programme.

I'm stuck as to why computerPick() function doesn't assign the new value to computer from random index??? Any help would be great!

```
let player = "heads";
let computer = null;

let gamePicks = ["heads", "tails"];

function computerPick() {
let randomIndex = gamePicks[Math.floor(Math.random() * gamePicks)];
computer = gamePicks[randomIndex];
}

function comparePicks() {
computerPick()
if (player === computer) {
    console.log(`This game was a tie with both players picking ${player}`);
} else if (player === "heads" && computer === "tails") {
    console.log(`Wooh player won with ${player}`);
} else console.log(`boooo computer won with ${computer}`);
}

comparePicks();
```

Comment: your line `let randomIndex = gamePicks[Math.floor(Math.random() * gamePicks)];` should be `let randomIndex = gamePicks[Math.floor(Math.random() * gamePicks.length)];`... `gamePicks.length` is the number of items in an array (in this case, 2), while `gamePicks` is the actual array.

Comment: Strange rules to win.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because you are trying to multiply an array value to a numeric value. Use below code instead:

```
let randomIndex = gamePicks[Math.floor(Math.random() * gamePicks.length)];
```